# Azure SQLMI - track users logging in to instance using Log Analytics

Tags: sql, azure, saas, azure-log-analytics

I'm looking for a way to list out who logged in to a SQL MI instance.
I have configured log analytics to receive all logs and metrics but see no login information in the logs. Looks like there is a flag in Azure SQL but this does not apply to SQL MI, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69579927/how-to-get-users-logging-information-using-log-analytics-in-azure-sql-database)
is where i found the flag.
Is there a way to enable this type of log collection in SQLMI so this information is sent to Log Analytics?
Can I get this info right from SQLMI? perhaps a system table?
Thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: When you configure diagnostic logs to log analytics, you should be able to select `SQLSecurityAuditEvents` to be sent to log analytics

Comment: Yes, I'm selecting AllLogs which includes SQLSecurityAuditEvents and audit when setting up Log Analytics but still see no data in any of the LogAnalytics tables (AzureActivity, AzureDiagnostics and Azure Metrics). This is what led me to believe I needed an extra step to start sending data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in addition to setting up LogAnalytics, an Audit job needs to be created within the DB in Master. Here is a link to the MSFT [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/auditing-configure?view=azuresql#set-up-auditing-for-your-server-to-event-hubs-or-azure-monitor-logs).